# Entity Framework Core - Relationships are not persisted at the same time. I have to make two DB inserts

Tags: sql, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I am trying to save relational data into a sql DB - 
I have a parentEntity and a childEntity
the parentEntity looks like this:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[ForeignKey("ChildObject")]
public int ParentObjectID { get; set; }
public Guid ParentGUID { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

The Child entity looks like this:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ChildObjectID { get; set; }
public int ParentObjectID { get; set; }
public string ChildName{ get; set; }
```

So you can see that the child has a FK to the parent.

Now if I add them to the same context :

```
_familyContext.Parent.Add(ParentObject);
_familyContext.Child.Add(ChildObject);
_familyContext.SaveChanges();
```

The insert fails - I have to save the parent, then get the entityID and add it to the child and then save the child.
Is it possible to do it at once?

Comment: Take a look at the docs to see how to properly define a one-many relationship: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships